# drag and drop image in image, not destroy the first

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a problem, I have two divs one with images and other without:

```
<div id="div1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
<img id="1" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"  src="image1.jpg" />
<img id="2" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"  src="image2.jpg" />
<img id="3" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"  src="image3.jpg" />
<img id="4" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"  src="image4.jpg" />       

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<br>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I want comunicate images between both divs.

The code "works" but I have a big problem is: when I drag one image in other, the first image selected disappears, drop() function?.
How can I avoid this?

UPDATE:

I create this function

```
function dropImg(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var clonado= document.getElementById(data);
  var padre =ev.target.parentNode['id'];

    ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(clonado,padre.firstChild);


}
```

and include on img tag

```
<img id="2" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="dropImg(event)" draggable="true"  src="image2.jpg" />
```

and the result: clone image inside the other iage

```
<img id="1" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="dropImg(event)" src="1.jpg">
<img id="2" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="dropImg(event)" scr=2.jpg />
</img>
```

Comment: On drag, clone the original and put it back in the same location.

Comment: thanks, I updated my code with new function, but doesn't works correctly, can you help me please